# Множественный захват

Tags: php, html, javascript

Я долго изучал php и приступил к практике, но потребовалось использование js. Код ниже захватывает Select блок при обработке и задает ему стиль. Наработка не моя, поэтому появилась проблема, она захватывает только option заранее заданные, а у меня они загружаются из php массива - в результате захватывается только первый. Как нужно изменить код для захвата всех option во всех селектах?

```
function reselect(select, addclass) {
addclass = typeof(addclass) != 'undefined' ? addclass : '';
$(select).wrap('<div class="sel_wrap ' + addclass + '"/>');
var sel_options = '';
var selected_option = false;
$(select).children('option').each(function() {
if($(this).is(':selected')){
selected_option = $(this).index();
}
sel_options = sel_options + '<div class="sel_option" value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).html() + '</div>';
});
var sel_imul = '<div class="sel_imul">\
<div class="sel_selected">\
<div class="selected-text">' + $(select).children('option').eq(selected_option).html() + '</div>\
<div class="sel_arraw"></div>\
</div>\
<div class="sel_options">' + sel_options + '</div>\
</div>';
$(select).before(sel_imul);
}
reselect('#ourselect1');
$('.sel_imul').live('click', function() {
$('.sel_imul').removeClass('act');
$(this).addClass('act');
if ($(this).children('.sel_options').is(':visible')) {
$('.sel_options').hide();
}
else {
$('.sel_options').hide();
$(this).children('.sel_options').show();
}
});
$('.sel_option').live('click', function() {
var tektext = $(this).html();
$(this).parent('.sel_options').parent('.sel_imul').children('.sel_selected').children('.selected-text').html(tektext);
$(this).parent('.sel_options').children('.sel_option').removeClass('sel_ed');
$(this).addClass('sel_ed');
var tekval = $(this).attr('value');
tekval = typeof(tekval) != 'undefined' ? tekval : tektext;
$(this).parent('.sel_options').parent('.sel_imul').parent('.sel_wrap').children('select').children('option').removeAttr('selected').each(function() {
if ($(this).val() == tekval) {
$(this).attr('selected', 'select');
}
});
});
var selenter = false;
$('.sel_imul').live('mouseenter', function() {
selenter = true;
});
$('.sel_imul').live('mouseleave', function() {
selenter = false;
});
$(document).click(function() {
if (!selenter) {
$('.sel_options').hide();
$('.sel_imul').removeClass('act');
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выполнять reselect('#ourselect1'); после каждой подгрузки из массива.